# Can I auto populate cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, automation

I have a bunch of categories; `Bar` `Foo` `Ghost` `Misc` `Other`

All have variable amounts - except for category `Ghost`, the amount is **always** `15.00`.

I have Data Validation set up (which is how I pick the category). I want to automate that when I pick `Ghost` as my category, it auto fills in the next cell (in Column B) with the amount `15.00`

[image: image example]

**Is this possible in Google Sheets?**

---

Note, my other categories can and do have variable numbers (including negatives).

**Update:** I'm hoping it'll ignore other cells which aren't in the `Ghost` category in row A.

Answer (score 1):

## workaround 1:

pre-populate **B2:B** with **`=IF($A(n)="Ghost", 15, )`**

- **B2**: **`=IF($A2="Ghost", 15, )`**
- **B3**: **`=IF($A3="Ghost", 15, )`**
- **B4**: **`=IF($A4="Ghost", 15, )`**
- **B5**: etc...

## workaround 2:

set conditional formatting to range **B2:B** to signalize the spot

- custom formula: **`=COUNTIF($A2, "Ghost")`**

## workaround 3:

have one more column pulling data from **B** column constructing the whole thing (conditional formatting is just a bonus to know which cells to skip in process of filling up **B** column)

- **C1**: **`={"Construct"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="Ghost", 15, B2:B))}`**

[image: 0]

Comment: I forgot to mention, this sheet is update daily, I'm constantly adding in new values (this only works to "prefill" the values for `Ghost` if everything else is empty. Can I make it ignore other cells if it isn't under the Ghost category in row A?

Comment: @WELZ answer updated. i also believe this script could be reshaped to solve your issue: webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99247

Answer (score -1):

Write the formula in cell B2 and drag it down:

```
=IF(A2="Ghost",15,"")
```